# Kivy not printing Backslash

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

For printing a newline in text of Label or any widget in kv file, it is done by `'\\n'`. To print a single quote, it is done by `'\\''` and similarly for double quotes, it is done by `'\\"'`. Then, why can't it print backslash if I do `'\\\'` ? On doing so, I get this error.

```
File "<string>", line 1
     '\'
       ^
 SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I found the answer. Its kinda weird that kv file follows weird set of rules to print backslash. It is done by `'\\\\'`.

Comment: not weird at all as when the kv file/string is read, `'\\\\'` is basically `'\\'` which when used by the interpreter is translated like `'\'`. It's like reading from file, then to `str()` and then `print()`